# BigQuery: Left Semi Join issue

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to write a SQL query that gets the number of times a name occurs in a table, where there is a JSON payload of that name. The idea here is to only get new entries to a table through type being 'CreateEvent'.

When I try to run this query, I get the following error:

> LEFT SEMI JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an equality
> of fields from both sides of the join

I'm not sure how to solve for this error, does anyone know where I'm going wrong?

**Query**

```
SELECT 
  tag.link, COUNT(tag.name) as count
FROM `table.day.20*`
WHERE 
  type="LookEvent"
  AND (_TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '1020' AND '1021')

  AND tag.link IN(
    SELECT tag.link FROM (
      SELECT tag.link, JSON_EXTRACT(payload, '$.reference') AS reference,
      FROM `table.day.20*`
      WHERE (_TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '1020' AND '1021') AND type = 'CreateEvent'
    )
    WHERE reference='"Liam"' OR reference  IS NULL # PublicEvent has no ref_type
  )
GROUP BY 
    tag.id, tag.name, tag.link
HAVING count >= 10
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 15
```

Comment: is tag an array column or an alias? If it not an array column, it is just alias issue. If it is array column, try rewriting your query with UNNEST function.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider  using the “UNNEST” statement in the subquery . You can refer to this documentation about [UNNEST](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#unnest_operator) and [JSON_EXTRACT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#other_json_functions).

You can see this example:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(json_text, '$') AS json_text_string
FROM UNNEST([
  '{"class" : {"students" : [{"name" : "Jane"}]}}',
  '{"class" : {"students" : []}}',
  '{"class" : {"students" : [{"name" : "John"}, {"name": "Jamie"}]}}'
  ]) AS json_text;
```

You can consider this approach by trying to use the “JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR” statement. You can see more [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#json_extract_scalar).

You can also see this example:

```
SELECT id
  , ARRAY(
      SELECT JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(x, '$.author.email') 
      FROM UNNEST(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(payload, "$.commits"))x
  ) emails
FROM `githubarchive.day.20180830` 
WHERE type='PushEvent' 
AND id='8188163772'
```